# How can I do something like React componentwillreceiveprops in vue

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

I sent props to child component by click event and then I use computed to take condition but I cant control newprops and oldprops. I dont need the computed take action every click. How can I do this?

Comment: You might want to look at something like `<div :key={prop} />`

Answer (score 1):

I think You Have to Use Watchers in vue
That watch always when data change
Follow this guideline
[Computed Property and Watchers in vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)